# Postgresql template iteration

Tags: postgresql

**Situation**

**t = template table**

```
i0 i1 i2 i3 i4 i5
aa ab cd ef gh ij
aa de gg jj kk dd
```

**r = verify tabel**

```
i0 i1 i2 i3 i4 i5
xx ab cd ef gh ij
xx de gg jj kk dd
yy ee cd ef gh ij
yy de gg jj kk dd
zz de gg jj kk dd
```

**Result with template and verify**

```
aa ab cd ef gh ij xx ab cd ef gh ij
aa de gg jj kk dd xx de gg jj kk dd
aa ab cd ef gh ij 
                  yy ee cd ef gh ij
aa de gg jj kk dd yy de gg jj kk dd
aa ab cd ef gh ij zz de gg jj kk dd
aa de gg jj kk dd
```

**Question:**

How can I verify the template table over 
the verify table? Full Join is only over all
I have to verify the template for xx and yy and zz.
Should I use a function with a for loop and full join
with the template table?

Comment: You can't have a result that has a different number of columns in different rows. And your obfuscated data doesn't really help to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution will be to `CROSS JOIN` template with a table that has one column with values `xx`,'yy`,`zz`.

```
SELECT t.*, v.*
FROM template AS t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 'xx' AS i0
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'yy'
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 'zz') AS foo
FULL JOIN verify AS v
  ON (foo.i0,t.i1,t.i2,t.i3,t.i4,t.i5) = (v.i0, v.i1, v.i2, v.i3, v.i4, v.i5);
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3998c/2)